# Standard Function for Escaping Strings in SQL

Tags: sql, .net-2.0, escaping

I'm writing a program in .NET2.0 and I need to escape the inputs before using them.  Unfortunately the standard parameter method system does not fully work in the system I'm using.  Using the ODBCCommand class I cannot place a ? parameter in the select part of the statement (which is required for the little bit of trickiness I'm doing) without getting an error, so I need to manually escape strings that may or may not contain a single quote (').  Any suggestions?

Edit- Example SQL:

As I would like it:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B)
SELECT (?, COLUMN_C)
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE COLUMN_D = ?
```

As it is:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B)
SELECT ('INPUT_VALUE_HERE', COLUMN_C)
FROM TABLE_B
WHERE COLUMN_D = ?
```

Edit: Sybase ASE is the DB driver, through ODBC

Comment: Can you give an example of the SELECT you are trying to execute?

Comment: If this is column name or table name etc. do not forget that attacker doesn't need a single quote to do injection. Otherwise ? supposed to work, isn't it?

Comment: Also what database are you using? Not all databases have the same set of escape characters and depending on where in the SELECT statement you are you may need different escape characters.

Comment: The example provided should work with a parameter. What is the database and what is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim s As String = "Michael O'Flatley"
Dim escapedString as String = s.Replace("'", "''")
```

Comment: I can't speak for Sybase ASE, but in SQL Server and Oracle you would only need to escape % (and _) if it is part of a `like` clause

Answer (score 3):

You can parse your string parameters with this extension function

```
public static string SqlEncode(string str)
{
    if (str == null) return String.Empty;
    return str.Replace("'","''");
}
```

Comment: to be an extension function should it be public static string SqlEncode(this string str)?

Comment: Good idea, but if you look you'll see this .NET2.0 (no extension methods).

Comment: I did not make it an extension because he said .NET 2.0.

Comment: Sorry Soni, you're right, I read extension in your answer and thought you meant to write an extension methos